# Unable to display parent-child heirarchy

Tags: ssas

I am creating a parent-child hierarchy in my dimension.
The AdventureWorks2012DW sample database is used.
I have set the ParentEmployeeKey, NameColumn property to LastName as per the wrox sql server 2012 book.
I have attached the Dimension Browser Image.[image]

I am  getting the Employee Key instead of LastName

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had to change the Employee Display NameColumn to LastName. 
And it worked!!! Thanks!!